# How can I omit html tags with displaying rte content on the TYPO3 frontend?

Tags: typo3, rte

I'm querying the text from an RTE (rich text editor) with fluid, so it gets displayed with the frontend, including the HTML tags (used with the RTE). How can I omit those HTML tags (and instead get them evaluated)? Why get they even displayed (as plain text)? I'm using the RTE with a custom content element. Should I review that element?

Comment: The question should be "*How can I render HTML*". Rudy's answer is valid, just Fluid doesn't try to render HTML by default by design. In big shortcuts, that's the matter of security. bonus tip: instead of using XML tags, you can also use short, inline syntax like `{myVariable->f.format.html()}` (also showed in the linked docs)

Comment: The question was not how to evaluate html tags but how to omit the evaluation of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Fluid are passed through `htmlspecialchars` by default when used directly in the template. To output HTML input in the backend RTE you need to surround it with a `<f:format.html>` tag. For example: `<f:format.html>{myVariable}</f:format.html>`. This also does things like add p-tags if needed, replace `<link...>` tags with actual links, etc. More on this ViewHelper you can find at https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/Html.html

If you want to add a variable as is, without any processing, you should surround it with a `<f:format.raw>` tag. For example: `<f:format.raw>{myVariable}</f:format>`. More on this ViewHelper you can find at https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/Format/Raw.html

Comment: The format.raw ViewHelper did it. Thank you for your help on this.